# Удаление папок в node.js

Tags: node.js

[image: Удаление]

Что он от меня просит? Почему не удаляет?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory not empty означает, что заданная директория все ещё содержит что-то, т.е. файлы или другие директории. Это и видно на вашей картинке. Отсюда и ошибка выполнения команды rmdir.

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.rmdir( path.join(__dirname,'dir'), 
          { recursive:true }, 
          (err) => { 
            console.error(err); 
          }
        );
```

Добавьте `{recursive:true}` вторым параметром для рекурсивного удаления содержимого директории.